# Is reflection from pockel cell normal?

Tags: optics, laser, microscopy

We are trying to align a laser for a 2-photon microscope and we noticed a reflection from the pockel cell. The reflection can be caught on the edge of the waveplate or the iris that are before the pockel cell but I am afraid that it is damaging the pockel cell itself. I have heard that pockel cells are quite sensitive and the beam should go through the exact center and I am worried that this reflection means that the beam is getting caught somewhere that it shouldn't and is damaging the pockel cell.
I appreciate any help on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Like any optic, there will be Fresnel reflection from the input and output faces of the Pockels cell. In fact, these reflections are very helpful in aligning the cell. If you notice that the reflection is visible on the edge of the iris before the cell, that's an indication that you're entering the cell at an angle rather than normal incidence. Try adjusting your alignment so that the reflection passes straight back through the aperture of the iris. Then you will know that you're passing through at normal incidence, which is important for proper alignment relative to the optic axis of the crystal and therefore performance of the Pockels cell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Brent.
My concern in this case is that if the reflection passes through the aperture, it will go back into the cavity and it would interfere with mode locking. How would I avoid that?